# How to enable or disable java console

Tags: java, testing

I am testing a java project but i don't know about java console. Have you any idea about Java Console & How to enable or disable it?

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error or problem? You need to discuss that, possibly including an example of some kind.

Comment: *"I am testing a java project"* An applet or JWS app.?  We need moer details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to control panel-->java -->advance-->java console 
and chose the state you want

Comment: thanks & I need some more help about " what is java console & how it is work? "

Comment: I think


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/console.html will be useful